# Can PDF streams using the FlateDecode filter be read incrementally?

Tags: java, pdf, stream, deflate, inflate

I am working on a library to read and render PDF files in Java. PDF streams are supposed to be read incrementally, but I don't know how this would work using the FlateDecode filter, because of the way that data is compressed. I can only decode the data if the whole stream is read and decoded, and not just a part.

Is it possible at all to read data like this incrementally? Or do I need to decode it all first?

Comment: *Is it possible at all to read data like this incrementally?* - what is your actual problem with incremental decoding? Due to the nature of the compression algorithm, you obviously have to start at the beginning of the stream. But whether you first decompress the whole stream into some array and forward that to post-processing or whether you forward the bytes as soon as you decode them (using some streaming architecture) obviously is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a deflate stream can be decompressed incrementally.  That is normally how it's done, using the `inflate()` function in zlib.  The interface to zlib's inflate in Java is the [`Inflater` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html) (unfortunately spelled wrong -- it should be Inflator).